# Disable auto suggestion for edittext with input type number

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers, autosuggest, android-inputtype

Below is the  code i am using for edittext which allows user to enter only numbers.

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/mobileHint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
            android:textColor="@color/numbertextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
```

To disable autosuggestions i changed

```
  android:inputType="number"
```

to

```
  android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
```

But with this my edittext also allow user to enter special characters listed in Num KeyPad.

I want to allow user to enter only numbers with auto suggestion off.

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

Comment: will numberSigned disable autosuggestion?

Comment: @Stranger autosuggestions on keyboard. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned|textNoSuggestions"` in xml wasn't working but

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

in java file worked for me.