# Disabling auto suggestion or clipboard for edit text with input type number

Tags: android, input, types, keyboard

I have an EditText (please see `et2` below) which needs to be of inputType `number`. When focused, it should not show any clipboard suggestions.

Now, for this I have tried setting `et2`'s inputType flag to
`textNoSuggestions` but it changes keyboard's inputType to text because of the flag.

Is there any way to disable clipboard suggestions and have the inputType set to "number" at the same time?

```
    val et1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext1)
    val et2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext2)
    et2.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS // shows no suggestion but changes to Text keyboard
```

Note: I have referred below solution, but it’s not working as expected.
[Disable auto suggestion for edittext with input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052770/disable-auto-suggestion-for-edittext-with-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using both properties

```
android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"

android:digits="0123456789"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried it for 'et2' edit text android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions" it show number keyboard along with other keys like special character and decimal. 
I want to show only number keyboard.

Comment: try to add android:digits="0123456789"

Comment: Or you can try inputType = "phone|textNoSuggestions"

Comment: Yes tried both solutions still its showing clipboard suggestions.